# cleaning urls with asp or aspx endings

Tags: regex

I would like to write an expression that matches and grabs everything after and including asp, but not when it is aspx.

Example:

`www.bla.asp1234` -> grab this

`www.bla.aspx123` -> don't grab this

I thought something like this would do -> `.*[asp][^x].+`
But it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Square brackets don't do what you think. Avoid them until you understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex like this ought to do what you want:

```
^.*\.asp(?:[^x\n].*)?$
```

See it in action: https://regex101.com/r/zC9oN6/1

Comment: It seems to not work. Firstly, # is just a random character (apologies if it seemed like it's part of my structure). Secondly, if I try /articles/fundamental/03/031203.asp. it will not work. I tried to alter your first example, by getting rid of $ then it worked for expressions like /articles/fundamental/03/031203.asp. but didn't work for expressions like dgets/dotomiscript.aspx

Comment: You need to post a more thorough set of examples, then.  Regarding your last example in your comment, I thought you didn't want to match `.aspx` ones?

Comment: I didn't, but it matches it as if it was an .asp expression. I will revise the question. Thank you for the feedback. By "didn't work for expressions like dgets/dotomiscript.aspx" I meant that it treated it as if it was a .asp expression which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Very solid control over regex. Much appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure, best of luck!